# jqgrid data loading in a button click everytime

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-php

I am using the below code to load the jqgrid data after button click. This is working when i click the button first time. while i click the button second time means it's not loaded. Please help me to solve this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready
        (
            function () {
                $('#btnContinue').live('click', function () {
                    var parent =  $('#hf_val').val();   
                        bindCustomers(parent);
                });
            }
        );

        var bindCustomers = function () {
            alert('in');
            // Set up the jquery grid
            $("#jqTable").jqGrid
                (
                    {
                        // Ajax related configurations
                        url: 'LoadCustomerData.ashx?TypeId='+ parent,
                        datatype: "json",
                        mtype: "POST",

                        // Specify the column names
                        colNames: ["CustomerId", "FirstName", "LastName"],

                        // Configure the columns
                        colModel: [
                                { name: "CustomerId", index: "CustomerId", width: 40, align: "left" },
                                { name: "FirstName", index: "FirstName", width: 100, align: "left" },
                                { name: "LastName", index: "LastName", width: 200, align: "left"}],

                        // Grid total width and height
                        width: 550,
                        height: 200,

                        // Paging
                        toppager: true,
                        pager: $("#jqTablePager"),
                        rowNum: 5,
                        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                        viewrecords: true, // Specify if "total number of records" is displayed

                        // Default sorting
                        //sortname: "Id",
                        //sortorder: "asc",

                        // Grid caption
                        caption: "A Basic jqGrid - Read Only"
                    }
                ).navGrid("#jqTablePager",
                    { refresh: true, add: false, edit: false, del: false },
                        {}, // settings for edit
                        {}, // settings for add
                        {}, // settings for delete
                        {sopt: ["cn"]} // Search options. Some options can be set on column level
                );
            alert('loading finish');
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: don't use .live, use .on

Comment: are you getting any errors on console when loaded for second time ?

Comment: No i didn't get any error

Comment: @user3036342 thats not a problem. Event fired every time correctly.

Comment: But the grid content url not fired..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see where your problem is. With this, you try to recreate the entire grid each time, instead of just reloading the data.

You're doing it through the URL (I'd suggest POST data to the URL instead, more chance of injection attacks)

Instead of re-creating it each time (or trying to) just call this on click:

```
$("#jqTable").setGridParam({'postData': data});
```

"data" would be something like 'TypeId=' + parent

Answer (score 0):

Create the grid outside the function and inside onclick just reload the grid. You dont have to create the whole grid every time u click. The variable parent can be added to postdata.